# Python - theano.scan() - return function values without feeding back into the loop

Tags: python, theano

Is it possible to return values calculated within the scan function without feeding them back into the scan function.

e.g.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

theano.config.exception_verbosity='high'
theano.config.optimizer='None'

def f(seq_v, prev_v):
    return seq_v*prev_v#, prev_v+1

a = T.dvector('a')

ini = T.constant(1, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

result, updates = theano.scan(fn=f,
                              outputs_info=[ini],
                              sequences=[a],
                              non_sequences=None)

fn  = theano.function(inputs=[a], outputs=result)

A = np.arange(1,5)
out = fn(A)

print 'Values:\nf:\t{}'.format(out)
```

which gives

```
Values:
f:  [  1.   2.   6.  24.]
```

However, I would like to output both of the values in `f()` without feeding the latter value back into the scan function:

```
def f(seq_v, prev_v):
    return seq_v*prev_v, prev_v+1
```

to give something like:

```
Values:
f:  [ [1. , 2.]   [2. , 3.]   [6. , 4.]  [24. , 5.] ]
```

*(I would just like to note that this problem is trivial but I would like to use the idea for debugging scan functions and checking output values)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `outputs_info` to be `None` for the output which you don't want to feed back into `f`. For further information, see [the `scan` documentation.](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html) Below is an example which should do what you want.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

theano.config.exception_verbosity='high'
theano.config.optimizer='None'

def f(seq_v, prev_v):
    return seq_v*prev_v, seq_v+1

a = T.vector('a')

ini = T.constant(1, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

result, updates = theano.scan(fn=f,
                              outputs_info=[ini,None],
                              sequences=[a])

fn  = theano.function(inputs=[a], outputs=result)

A = np.arange(1,5, dtype=T.config.floatX)
out = fn(A)

print('Values:\nf:\t{}'.format(out))
```

Output:

```
Values:
f:  [array([  1.,   2.,   6.,  24.], dtype=float32), array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.], dtype=float32)]
```